# Type Error: (slice(None, None, None), array([ True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm preparing my dataset for test, train, split in python and am having an issue. I'm trying to assign X to all columns except Churn_Yes and y to Churn_Yes only. However, when I run the below code, it returns an error of

Type Error: (slice(None, None, None), array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,

```
X=df_final[:, df_final.columns != 'Churn_Yes']
y=df_final['Churn_Yes']
```

Thinking there was something wrong with my df_final, I ran df.head() to check the results and everything looks normal. Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: `X= X=df_final` might be a typo?

Comment: Good catch. That happened when I tried retyping everything in the cell in an attempt to fix the issue, Unfortunately, it's giving me the same error.

Comment: And better to use `loc` and `iloc` in this case. Looks like Exploore wrote a sample answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `loc` or `iloc` for value access using Boolean

```
import pandas as pd
df_final = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name_1','Name_2','Name_3','Churn_Yes','Churn_Yes'])

print(df_final.columns != 'Churn_Yes')
X=df_final.loc[:, df_final.columns != 'Churn_Yes']
#  X=df_final.iloc[:, df_final.columns != 'Churn_Yes']
y=df_final['Churn_Yes']

print(y)
print(X)
```

---

By [User:SeaBean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15070697/seabean) :
Without `loc` and `iloc` use this statement instead of above

```
X=df_final[df_final.columns[df_final.columns != 'Churn_Yes']]
```

Comment: Is it a typo for "Without loc and iloc" ?  Should it be `df_final[df_final.columns[df_final.columns != 'Churn_Yes']]` ?

Comment: @SeaBean thanks for correcting me, I will change it